# How to zoomin the webpage using mouse in selenium python or robot framework using selenium library?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

i want to test the zoom functionality of a web application using robot framework selenium library. Also wanted to know if it could be done using selenium webdriver in python.

I want to zoom the webpage.

To do so i have tried something like below

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(canvas_element)
.send_keys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD)).build().perform();
```

But this gives me an error below

```
AttributeError: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'
```

How can i fix this. could someone help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

Try with this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='40%'")
```

and then revert to normal zoom with:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='100%'")
```

Comment: how can i do the same only for canvas element using mouse scroll. thanks

Comment: hmm thanks. it doesnt actually zoom the element or neither the webpage....

Comment: Well, I have to find a solution as you've accepted the answer, try the edit.